# How to open a pdf in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, pdf

It is very odd, I added a network drive and can see the files on it. Now I can open some files, but not pdfs. I can open text files and .doc files, but for pdfs I get following error message:

```
Unable to open document “file:///media/folder/file.pdf”.

Failed to load backend for 'application/pdf': libzstd.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I tried copying the file onto my drive and opening it then, same problem. I also tried opening this: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf but it also doesn't work. So I can't open pdfs in general.
The strange thing is my collegue also has Ubuntu 20.04 and we both have a fresh default install of Ubuntu and he can open it, but I can't. I didn't change anything regarding the document viewer. How can I open pdfs in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Can you try a right click, then "Open With", and then try opening it with Firefox, or whatever web browser you have. Alternatively, you can copy this address of the file (`file:///media/folder/file.pdf`) that you have given, and paste it directly in the search bar of the browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after shortly switching to Windows and then back again, so restarting the computer this works again. I'm still curious how it could happen that such a basic thing as opening pdfs got broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think your default PDF viewer is broken. Please try
reinstall evince,qpdfview or somethink like app.
On 18.04, they can be installed like:
sudo apt install evince qpdfview
(no sure if 20.04 is same or not)

Comment: Removing evince and re-installing it with snap made it for me. Running Ubuntu 20.04.